# index.php in Wordpress showing PHP source code after moving site

Tags: wordpress

I moved my site to a new server and it all went smooth, but now when I access the home page I get this weird behavior:

- When the URL is typed, the PHP source code of the file index.php is shown, not the normal content.
- If I type the URL of any subpage, I can see the subpage perfectly, and
- If I type www.myurl.com/?preview=true I can see the home page perfectly (this one has me lost).

The old version of the site was made with Wordpress too and it was working fine until I replaced it with this new installation.

I have no idea what is going on, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would contact your hosting provider. This sounds like a server configuration issue.

Comment: Are you certain that the server is PHP friendly?

Comment: @Daniel I know the server is PHP friendly because the previous installation was a Wordpress site. That's the whole reason why I'm so intrigued with the issue.

Comment: @SamPlusPlus This is gonna be my next step for sure, just wanted to try to fix it myself first. Thank you both.